Prove that $18 \mid a^3+b^3+c^3 \implies 6\mid abc $
This is a problem from my RMO mock test

Prove that $18 \mid a^3+b^3+c^3 \implies 6\mid abc $ for integers $a$, $b$, $c$.

Attempt:
Recall that: $$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a+b+c)^3 - 3(a^2b + b^2a + ac^2 + a^2c + bc^2 + b^2c) - 6abc$$
$$ 18 \mid (a+b+c)^3 - 3(a^2b + b^2a + ac^2 + a^2c + bc^2 + b^2c) - 6abc $$
$$\implies 3 \mid (a+b+c)^3 \implies 3 \mid (a+b+c)$$
Similarly,
$$ 2 \mid (a+b+c)^3 - 3(a^2b + b^2a + ac^2 + a^2c + bc^2 + b^2c)$$
Which may be stated as,
$$ (a+b+c)^3 \equiv (a^2b + b^2a + ac^2 + a^2c + bc^2 + b^2c) \pmod{2}$$
$$\implies (a+b+c)^3 \equiv 2(ab + bc + ca) \pmod{2}$$
$$\implies 2 \mid (a+b+c)$$
Combining these,
$$ 6 \mid (a+b+c)$$
$$\implies 18 \mid 3(a^2b + b^2a + ac^2 + a^2c + bc^2 + b^2c) - 6abc$$

How do you finish after this? Must you resort to case work? Or are there any quick observations that finish off the problem? I noticed that $ 2 | (a^2b + b^2a + ac^2 + a^2c + bc^2 + b^2c)$, but nothing came to mind after that.

You are overthinking it. Each cube can only be $0,,1\text{ or }8 \pmod 9$. The rest is a little casework.

I want to avoid casework AS MUCH as possible, but yes, that is a solution I missed

I would account for $2$ separately. If you have all $a,b,c$ odd, then it can't be divisible by $2$. So at least one is even. therefore the RHS is divisible by 2

By the dupe $3$ divides one of $a,b,c$, and same for $2$ (else all are odd contra given sum of cubes is even).

Continuing your line of work:
$$6|a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b-2abc=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-4abc\equiv -5abc$$
since $a+b\equiv -c\bmod 6$ etc.
and so $6|abc.$

Why $-4abc\equiv -5abc \pmod{6}$? Shouldn't it be $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c) \equiv -abc \pmod{6}$?

that is not what I wrote ?

Can you explain the second line?

It looks like you are prepating for olympads so it would be beneficial if you figure out that one tiny detail on your own. What could I have possibly meant when I wrote
$$a+b\equiv -c \pmod 6$$ ?

Alright, as I understand it:
$$2abc \equiv (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) - 2abc \equiv -abc -2abc \equiv - 3abc \equiv 3abc \pmod{6}$$ And thus $abc \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$. I think thats correct?

more or less yeah. Key is $$\prod (a+b)\equiv\prod (-c)=-abc\pmod 6$$

You can write it with elementary symmetric polynomials:
\begin{align*}
18|a^3+b^3+c^3&=(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)+3abc\\
\implies 3&|(a+b+c)^3\\
\implies 3&|a+b+c\\
\implies 9&|(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\\
\implies 9&|3abc\\
\implies 3&|abc\\
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
2&|a^3+b^3+c^3\\
\implies 2&|a+b+c\\
\implies 2&|(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\\
\implies 2&|3abc\\
\implies 2&|abc\\
\end{align*}

Anything that continues down my line of thought? Although this is very elegant, I most likely wouldn't have thought of it.

A much simpler way to solve:
Every integer $x$ satisfies $x^3 \pmod{18}$ is in $\{0,1,8\}$. It is easy to check that the only way then that $18$ could divide $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is either if (A) or (B) below is true:

(A) The equation $a^3 \pmod{18} = b^3 \pmod{18} = c^3 \pmod{18} = 0$ holds.

(B) The relations [or a permutation thereof] $a^3 \pmod{18} = 1$, $b^3 \pmod{18} = 8$, or $c^3 \pmod{18} = 9$.


If on the one hand (A) is true and the equation $a^3 \pmod{18} = b^3 \pmod{18} = c^3 \pmod{18} = 0$ holds however, then all of $a,b,c$ must be a multiple of $6$ so clearly the product is a multiple of $6$. If on the other hand (B) is true and the relations $a^3 \pmod{18} = 1$, $b^3 \pmod{18} = 8$, or $c^3 \pmod{18} = 9$ hold, then $b$ must be a multiple of $2$ and $c$ must be a multiple of $3$, and so the product $abc$ must be a multiple of $6$.
